# How to get the width and height of a Button or Image that is constrained using Guidelines

Tags: android, button, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I am thoroughly confused here. I have tried to dynamically set the height and width of an image based on a button that has been sized based on Constraint Layout's guidelines. This will enable the application to size the Image to the correct size based on the screen size so it will work on all devices, or that is my goal.

Here is the code I am using:

```
ImageView snellen;
Button ghostButton;

private final double HEIGHT_RATIO = 11/8.5;
//private final double DISTANCE_RATIO = 120/8.5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_snellencharttest);

    snellen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.snellen);
    ghostButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ghostButton);

    snellen.setX(ghostButton.getX());
    snellen.setY(ghostButton.getY());

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) snellen.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = ghostButton.getWidth();
    params.height = (getHeightRatio(ghostButton.getHeight(), HEIGHT_RATIO));

    snellen.setLayoutParams(params);

    System.out.println("########################################################################### WIDTH: " + snellen.getWidth());
    System.out.println("########################################################################### HEIGHT: " + snellen.getHeight());


    ghostButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

private int getHeightRatio(int ghostHeight, double ratio) {
    double calc = ghostHeight*ratio;
    return ((int) Math.round(calc));
}
```

To explain what I am attempting to do: I have a button that is placed into my xml by constraint which I will provide code for below. What I wanted to do is get the x and y position of that button, then the height and width and pretty much layer the Image over where the button lies. In this example I am getting the width of the button "screen" and then setting the height to be a ratio of the original image size. Then make the button disappear because I am using it for a reference.

But as you can see I included some SOP's that will tell me what the height and width of the image is. These both return 0. I am confused because when I look at the image, it is definitely bigger than 0 by 0. Is this making it so the image will just scale as big as it can to fit the screen? If so, that is what I am hoping to achieve but I need to be able to get the width and height of that image.

Here is my xml which might be useful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- ____________________________________________ VERTICAL _________________________________ -->

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/uno"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/dos"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95"/>

<!-- __________________________________________ HORIZONTAL _________________________________ -->

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/firstRail"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/secondRail"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1"/>

<!-- __________________________________________ ECT __________________________________________-->

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:id="@+id/snellen"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/eyechart"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-7dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/secondRail" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/ghostButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/firstRail"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/uno"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/dos"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/secondRail"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I just put the ImageView in some random corner because I will be resizing it later, and it does in fact change positions and sizes so I assumed my program was doing what I wanted.

As I said earlier, is the problem the fact that the buttons `layout_width` and `layout_height` are set to 0 and it is just sized based on constraints? If so, my question changes to: How can I get the width and height from an image/button that is constrained, and `layout_width` and `layout_height` are 0?

Any insight to this is appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT:**

Before showing the edit, a small sidenote that may or may not be pertinent: The image I am using is extremely large. I not only had to add it to my `drawable-xhdpi` but I also had to add this line into my manifest or my app would crash: `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`

Thanks to Muthukrishnan Rajendran, I added a post in my onCreate to wait for the view to be fully loaded, which helped me get the width and height. Unfortunately when I added that in, my image no longer shows up. I have put everything inside the run like so:

```
 ghostButton.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            snellen.setX(ghostButton.getX());
            snellen.setY(ghostButton.getY());

            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) snellen.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = ghostButton.getWidth();
            params.height = (getHeightRatio(ghostButton.getHeight(), HEIGHT_RATIO));

            snellen.setLayoutParams(params);

            System.out.println("########################################################################### WIDTH: " + snellen.getWidth());
            System.out.println("########################################################################### HEIGHT: " + snellen.getHeight());

            ghostButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Is this correct? Is there something that is inside the run that is making my image not show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the width and height after the view attached to the screen, It should be complete after `onCreate` method,

Then how?

You can use like this

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }

    });
```

so the run method will get the call after this item will be attached to the activity screen

So for your case for example if you want to get the x and y for  `ghostButton` you should do like this,

```
ghostButton.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                snellen.setX(ghostButton.getX());
                snellen.setY(ghostButton.getY());
            }
        });
```

Comment: And this would just go inside my onCreate?

Comment: yes, you can write inside onCreate, run method will get the call when it attached.

Comment: Sweet! It looks like, based on my SOP's, that it is indeed adjusting the width and height. My only problem is that the image isn't showing up now. I put everything inside this run method (from the `setX` to when I make `ghostButton` invisible). Should I be putting everything inside the post or should I only include the `setX` and `setY`. EDIT: I show what I changed in my eidt to my OP

Comment: if you want to do any calculation based on that you can do it inside run, but one small question to you, Why can't we adjust in XML itself..? Could you add the expected Screen shot, so that we and do that in XML itself..? just a suggestion.

Comment: I had no idea that you could do it inside xml. I have tried multiple methods to adjust the height based on something else but xml being a markup language is pretty limited. And also I don't have an expected screen shot bc it isn't working sorry. Right now it is just a blank white screen because I make the button invisible and the image is not showing up

Comment: In your layout, you just want one button and the image view..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150845/discussion-between-cjnash-and-muthukrishnan-rajendran).